# visual studio debugger - watch pointer casting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have some ugly lagacy code that i try to understand and want to debug.

Situation:

```
class A{
// some members and functions
// but no virtual ones
};

class B:public A
{
// contains virtual methods
}

class C:public B
{}

// now somewhere there is an array of pointers to A;
A* someList[FixSize];

// and another struct contains a pointer to that someList.
struct T{
 A** list;
}t;
```

the array elements of `someList` are actually of type `C`. since `A` does not contain any virtual methods the debugger only shows the A elements in that list and does not offer the child classes member in its tree-view.

Casting the `list` pointer to `C**` obviously is not working, since there is an offset between the `C`-object and its `A` part.

if setting `(C*)(t->list[0])` as a watch then the debugger shows the correct Data. but it is not very convenient inspecting 50 objects in that way.

Does anybody know some smart way to handle this.

Comment: Try `(C*)(t->list[0]),FixSize`. You might need to use an actual number rather than `FixSize`. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/06/05/size-specifier-how-to-display-a-c-c-pointer-as-an-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger.aspx)

Comment: @Simple this would only work if the objects are in memory in the same order as in the list. that is not the case.

Comment: If you are using new version of VS (ex: 2013), you could play with Debugger Visualizers (and make one for custom types, this visualizers can be share between coworkers for solving this problem to other people) [VS Visualizers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx), [How to make then](http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83).

Comment: Are you allowed to add a virtual destructor to A?  If you can do that, then (C**)t->list,50 will just work.

Comment: @cup sadly i can not add any virtual methods since that would break some code that relies on the inner structure of A :-( - difficult to explain, but in short: no

Answer (score 0):

`(C**)t->list,10` is working tested in Visual Studio 2010.
As per your `struct T {} t` definition, it should be `(C**)(t.list),10`